# Using the mitt-library in Vue with Webpack hot-reload causes problems?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, eventemitter

In my Vue3 app, I'm using the `mitt` eventbus library to emit and receive events between components.

I put this in `onMounted` of a list component that needs to refresh:

```js
  mitt.on("list_refresh", (evt) => {
    refresh();
  });
```

In another component that contains the list-component as a child (or grandchild), I do this in a method:

```js
  mitt.emit("list_refresh", {});
```

This works ok, but while developing with `hot-reload` on, the events seem to be emitted multiple times, as if they're created extra each time the app reloads, instead of overwriting the old ones.
When I reload the entire page in the browser, it works fine again.

Any idea to prevent this?

Comment: This means that either mitt.on or mitt.emit is called twice. You could debug both scenarios on your side. The reason this happens depends on the project. You may want to check how hot reload works. These days it doesn't reload the whole window as this would be inefficient, only relevant pieces of an app.

Comment: mitt.on is called for each time the component was reloaded. If I put a console.log in the function and change the text, the component reloads and it triggers the function multiple times. it even shows the old text (and another one with the new text) !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your component is missing a corresponding [`off()` call](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mitt#off) to remove the event listener. During hot reload, the current component instances unmount, and new ones mount; so if you're not removing current event listeners, you'll just pile on new event listeners. To resolve the issue, use the [`onUnmounted` hook](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#lifecycle-hooks) to remove the event listener when the component is removed from the DOM.

Also, make sure to pass *cached function references* (instead of inline functions) to `mitt.on()` and `mitt.off()` to ensure the given event listener lookup succeeds in `mitt.off()`:

```js
// mitt.on('list_refresh', () => refresh()) ❌

mitt.on('list_refresh', refresh) ✅
mitt.off('list_refresh', refresh)
```

Your `setup()` should look similar to this:

```js
import { onMounted, onUnmounted } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const refresh = () => { /*...*/ }

    onMounted(() => mitt.on('list_refresh', refresh))
    onUnmounted(() => mitt.off('list_refresh', refresh)) 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Not passing a callback seems to also work: `onUnmounted(() => mitt.off('list_refresh')`